# In Node.js, how would you write a unit test page speed?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, hapi.js

I'm working on a site replatform/redesign.  We are going to use Node.js and Hapi.  I would like to add unit test that will measure page load speed. Is there a way to do this using Mocha and Chai?  Are there any frameworks that are dedicated to page speed testing specifically?

Comment: That would more of an integration test than a unit test.

Comment: Tools like ab* (apache benchmark) measures it. Page load speed depends on a number of factors. [Google Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) is good too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mansfield mentioned what you're looking for is a integration test and not a unit test.

I'd recommend using phantomjs and review the HAR data that's available which will show you time to first byte, and other end user experience metrics.

Here's a link to one of the examples: [loadspeed.js computes the loading speed of a web site](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/loadspeed.js)

And here's one on the HAR data: [netsniff.js captures network traffic in HAR format](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/netsniff.js)

If you are not familiar with HAR data - then think of what you see in firebug or Chrome's network tab.  You can upload the HAR file into [viewers on the web like this one](http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/)

When you test you'll want to put some traffic to your application and as previously mentioned by @Alvin K. AB can send a bunch of requests to a page to simulate some load on the app.

For a more "node" approach than Apache's AB tool there's [wrk - Modern HTTP benchmarking tool](https://github.com/wg/wrk).